# Скрипт, добавляющий ссылки на файлы в БД, при этом меняющий их местоположение.

Tags: php, mysql

Возможно, заголовок не внес ясность в суть моего вопроса, поэтому начну все сначала.
Существует папка, существует скрипт, загружающий в эту папку файлы(изображения). - это все гуд. Далее: существует скрипт, который добавляет ссылки на те самые файлы в MySQL. Вот он:

```
<?php
include('mysql.php');
if ($handle = opendir('images')) {
 while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
  if($file!='.' && $file!='..') {
   $images[] = "('".$file."')";
  }
 }
 closedir($handle);
}
$query = "INSERT INTO images (filename) VALUES ".implode(',', $images)." ";
if (!mysql_query($query)) {
 print mysql_error();
}
else {
 print "Изображение подтверждено!";

}

?>
```

Далее мне требуется ваша помощь, люди добрые. 
Мне нужно, чтобы файлы загружались временно в одну папку, там индексировались в MySQL, затем перемещались в другую директорию навсегда, при этом чтобы далее корректно отображались, т.к. из временной папки они будут удалены.
Надеюсь на вашу понятливость :)

Comment: ну перемещайте их, кто мешает... а в images указывайте что complete moved или еще как. чтобы движок знал  где искать эти картинки.

Comment: Функции rename() или copy() и перемещайте - в чем проблема та?

Answer (score 1):

ответ из комментария

---

Функции `rename()` или `copy()` — и перемещайте